# File downloding from mysql database in cakephp with sample code

Tags: cakephp, download

I need some sample understandable code for downloading file from mysql database in cakephp. Please provide sample code with explanation and also provide reference url if any. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way woudl be something like bellow. But I would suggest to look at media views for more robust solution.

Firstly, your database has to have column of type blob (so it can store raw file data) , filename, and its good to store and content type.

then in your controller "files_controller"

```
function download (filename)
{

$file = $this->Files->find('first', array('conditions' => array('filename' => $filename));

header("Content-type: ".$file->content_type); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file->filename."\"");

echo $file->content;
@flush(); 
@ob_end_flush(); 
exit();
}
```

so if you have link like `<a href='files/download/myfile.txt'> Download </a>` the controller would force headers and content of a file , and  force download to a user.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views http://book.cakephp.org/view/1434/HTML if you going to help with questions marked 'cakephp' use the cakephp methods for doing things.

Comment: MediaViews woudl NOT force donwload a file. It will only download a file that physiclly exist on a system.

Comment: @ElijanSejic : thanks for your answer, I don't know whether it's a good way or not, but I have already tried that and It works, Thanks a lot